# How to get XPath for the text after the <b> tags

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

I Need to get XPath for the following, to get the text after the `<b>` tags

```
<li class="SpacedOut">
<b>Name 6:</b> 
    "ABC" 
<b>Name 1:</b>
    "BCD"
<b>Name 2:</b>
    "EFG" 
<b>Name 3:</b>
    "HIJ" 
 <b>Name 4:</b>
    "KLM"
 <b>Name 5:</b>
    "NOP"    
 <br>
```

I need to get the following texts from the above HTML, please help how to set XPath to get the following text

> Required output: "ABC" "BCD" "EFG" "HIJ" "KLM" "NOP"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible using just XPath, but there may be some advanced stuff I'm unaware of.

This is fairly simple using regular expression matching though:

```
        driver.get("https://1a9f9143-5107-46d6-85df-3b5fc765cd60.htmlpasta.com");

        WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.className("SpacedOut"));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(list.getText());

        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

The regex may need adjusting if your real text is substantially different from what you supplied.  I would suggest researching Java regular expressions in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can work with to get the strings you are looking to fetch from the HTML you have shared in the question,

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<title>Test</title>

<body>
    <li class="SpacedOut">
        <b>Name 6:</b>
        "ABC"
        <b>Name 1:</b>
        "BCD"
        <b>Name 2:</b>
        "EFG"
        <b>Name 3:</b>
        "HIJ"
        <b>Name 4:</b>
        "KLM"
        <b>Name 5:</b>
        "NOP"
        <br>
</body>

</html>
```

**Java:**

```
try {
    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("file:///home/milin/test.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    String s = null;
    List<WebElement> allB = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li/b"));
    int bCount = allB.size();
    for (WebElement b : allB) {
        String wrapperText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='SpacedOut']")).getText().trim();
        String bText = b.getText();
        s = wrapperText.substring(wrapperText.indexOf(bText));
        wrapperText = s.trim();
        wrapperText = wrapperText.replace(bText, "").trim();
        if (wrapperText.contains(" ")) {
            wrapperText = wrapperText.substring(0, wrapperText.indexOf(" "));
        }
        System.out.println(wrapperText);
    }

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output:**

```
"ABC"
"BCD"
"EFG"
"HIJ"
"KLM"
"NOP"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `//li[@class='SpacedOut']/text()` 
You'll be able to return it into a list if you're using Selenium

Answer (score -1):

You can try this XPath, this should make it:

```
"//li[@class='SpacedOut']/text()[normalize-space()]"
```

Good luck!

Comment: Also, you can get the specified text(inner html content)  instead of using WebElement list  `//li[@class="SpacedOut"]/text()[normalize-space()][2]` This will get the text **"BCD"** for Other text content change the position from **[1] to [5]**